How to achieve 2D product preview images?
I want to implement a product customization function, which renders the final effect image for users to preview by uploading customized images. For example, here are two bleeding images of products. Based on the bleeding images, we can crop the user-uploaded pictures and generate finished product renderings.The images in the renderings may be specific perspectives of the product, and rendering involves modifying the shape of the image.
I have attempted to use canvas to crop images uploaded by users. I calculated the path of the largest transparent area based on the bleed map, intending to apply it to custom image cropping, but the cropping results were unsatisfactory. Additionally, I am unsure of how to process the image during rendering. As a novice in this area, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for feasible implementation solutions. Ideally, providing some demo examples would be extremely helpful for me to understand and implement this functionality.
right part
left part
Preview of renderings

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
